# Accessing same Iterator list from different classes

Tags: java

I have a  class that adds/removes items to an iterator, is it possible to access those items of that same list from a separate class?

Comment: Normally, It's not possible to add/remove from iteratirs , which are immutable..... Unless you've done something special to your iterator or created your own implementation.

Comment: [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) does not have `add()` or `remove()` methods. Are you talking about [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)s?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as long as you have a reference to the list, or references to the individual items of interest.